# Regular expression for series of numbers in ruby

Tags: ruby, regex

I am trying to match a pattern as given below

```
pattern: file.update.20120304.xml
     file.update.1.xml
     file.update.201203040002.xml
```

If i have to match the pattern leaving the numbers file.update..xml
how can I do in ruby?

Comment: what's you source string and what the exact output you want?

Comment: What have you tried already? Have you [seen the docs for Regexp](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Regexp.html)? It has some helpful examples.

Comment: @RubyLovely I'm assuming they want to extract `201203040002` from `file.update.201203040002.xml`, but that's a very good question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
"file.update.20120304.xml"[/\d+/]     # => "20120304"
"file.update.1.xml"[/\d+/]            # => "1"
"file.update.201203040002.xml"[/\d+/] # => "201203040002"
```

Comment: I didn't know that notation. Thx. But the regexp is wrong as `"file.1545.update.1.xml"[/\d+/]` returns the first occurrence `1545`.

Comment: @toch Where did `"file.1545.update.1.xml"` come from? Why is the regexp wrong?

Comment: it's another string not following the pattern. I've assumed, nothing shouldn't be returned in that case. But maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: +1 for the syntax, it's not seen enough.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Regexp](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Regexp.html) and [gsub](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/String.html#method-i-gsub) to extract the numbers

```
filename = 'file.update.20120304.xml'
numbers = filename.gsub(/\Afile\.update\.(\d+)\.xml\z/, '\1')
```

The used regexp is composed as following:

- a first part `file\.update\.` to be sure you have "file.update"
- a middle part `([0-9]+)` to have one or more number
- an end part `\.xml` to be sure to have ".xml" at the end
- the anchors `\A` and `\z` for the beginning and the end of the string

The middle part is wrapped with `()` to be a Regexp variable that you can reuse in the replacement string as `\1`

**Update with `variableName[/regular expression/]`**

```
filename = 'file.update.20120304.xml'
numbers = filename[/\Afile\.update\.(\d+)\.xml\z/, 1]
```

It returns the first captured group, i.e. between `()`.

Comment: awesome, I never knew, ppl would respond so quick in Stack overflow...I am amazed..thanks all, and toch your code worked perfectly.. I would be reciving file names like the pattern I mentioned but I just want to match leaving the <numbers> within them

Comment: Or you could just use `\d+`

Comment: @Krish I've updated my answer to extract the numbers

Answer (score 1):

```
p "file.update.201203040002.xml".split(".") .map { |x|  x if x.to_i != 0}.compact[0].to_i
#=> 201203040002
p "file.update.20120304.xml".split(".") .map { |x|  x if x.to_i != 0}.compact[0].to_i
#=> 20120304
```

Comment: @iain I am not strong on `regex`, thus always trying to by pass it ;)

Comment: :). it returns the first number group. with `"file.24554.update.20120304.xml"` you'll get `24554`. For me, it shouldn't return anything for that case.

Comment: @toch umm, I think what OP asked it will work for him/her.  If he needs your example to work,can modify it. :)